# Plots not showing in Plots window, but showing in R itself

Tags: ggplot2, rstudio, version

I am using UBUNTU. When I code a plot and enter it, the plot does not pop up in the bottom right "Plots" window in RStudio. Instead it pops up inside my actual R. I get the following error: **Warning message:
R graphics engine version 16 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed.**
My R is currently version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16) "Beagle Scouts" and my RStudio is R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16) "Beagle Scouts".
BUT! when I open RStudio, it tells me that my version is not up to date and when I check for updates in RStudio is tells me: "RStudio 2023.06.1 +524 is now available (you're using 2022.07.2 +576)"
So it seems comfused,
Can anyone assist?

Thank you!

I tried to download the new R and Rstudio but it didnt help